# Cross-browser client-side redirection in a new tab or window

Tags: http, browser, cross-browser, redirect

we need a kind of client-side redirection and the only options we have are:

1. `window.location`
2. `window.open`
3. HTTP 301, 302, 303 responses

window.location doesn't support opening the target location in a new tab or window. (I think this is related to [browsing context](http://www.thoughtresults.com/browsing-context))

window.open doesn't work in Chrome and seems to be dependent upon some client-side configurations made to the browser, which makes it a less favorable option, since we don't have control on it.

HTTP redirect response doesn't open a new tab or window, just like `window.location`.

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "window.open doesn't work in Chrome"? That's not a generally true statement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with this for hours last night, I had a flash of inspiration this morning, and I have just tested this solution in FF3, Chrome, IE7 and IE8 - it's a bit hacky but it works in all.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Redirect in a new window</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function doIt () {
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.action = 'http://www.google.com/';
        form.target = '_blank';
        document.getElementById('hidden_div').appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      #hidden_div {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      This is my page content<br />
      <a href="http://www.google.com/">This is a link to Google</a>...<br />
      ...and this button will open Google in a new tab or window: <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="doIt();" />
    </div>
    <div id="hidden_div"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

### How It Works

You need a hidden `<div>` on your page somewhere that you can get a reference to in JS (no big deal - just create one with `display: none`).

When you want to do the redirect, use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) to create a new `<form>` element, assign it's `action` attribute with the address of the page where you want to take the user, and give it a `target` attribute as appropriate (I have used `_blank` in my example above). Then simply append it to your hidden `<div>` and call it's `submit()` method.

Hey presto, your redirect opens in a new window/tab!

Unfortunately you are still at the mercy of how the user configures their browser to handle `target="_blank"` but it will be either a new window or a new tab, and it should work everywhere...